# Can I use the theorem of differentiation under the integral sign for $ F(x,y) = \int_\sqrt{x}^\sqrt{y} \cos (t^2) \, dt $?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Given
>
> $$ F(x,y) = \int_\sqrt{x}^\sqrt{y} \cos (t^2) \, dt $$
>
> i. Determine the set of definition of $F$
>
> ii. Write, where does exist, the gradient of $F$

i. We can easily see that the function $F(x,y)$ is defined for $x \geq 0$, $ y \geq 0$

ii. For this one I was thinking of using the theorem  of differentiation under the integral sign since the conditions for the theorem are verified for $x,y > 0$

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Why not just utilize the fundamental theorem of calculus? Because the integrand $\cos(t^2)$ does not involve any of the variables $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You mean to use the chain rule? @SangchulLee

Comment: Indeed. You may define $G(t)$ as an antiderivative of $\cos(t^2)$ and write $F(x)=G(\sqrt{y})-G(\sqrt{x})$. This should make the analysis on the differentiability of $F$ much straightforward.

Comment: The whole thing may also be view as a particular case of [Leibniz rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241942).

Comment: In this particular case I would substitute $u=t^2$ to get $$F(x,y)={1\over 2}\int\limits_x^y{\cos u \over \sqrt{u}}\,du$$ The integrated function is slightly uglier but the endpoints are nicer.